# Incrementing button with javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

## JS CODE

```
var currentindex = 0;
function addInput() {

    var lastinput = document.getElementById('input' + currentindex);
    if(lastinput.value != '') {
        var container = document.getElementById('inputcontainer');
        var newinput = document.createElement('input');
        currentindex++;
        newinput.type = "text";
        newinput.name = 'input' + currentindex;
        newinput.id   = 'input' + currentindex;
        newinput.onkeyup = addInput;
        container.appendChild(newinput);
    }
}
```

## HTML CODE

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="inputcontainer">
<input type="text" name="input0" id="input0" onkeyup="addInput();" />
<button type="button">clickme</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, the new input box is incremented every time, but the button is not incremented according to the input boxes. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "increment the button"? Where is the code that is supposed to do that?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i just want the box to add all the time when the input box creates

Comment: @Yuan can u post it as an answer

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. The language barrier appears strong between us, you may have to describe what you want to achieve in more words than that. Maybe add a couple of sentences to your question?

Comment: @user3830347 you should make us understand you. use pictures if you need to. yes, draw the thing you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other has stated in comment, you are missing the button append part. So you need to create new `button` and append it to the **container** :

```
var container = document.getElementById('inputcontainer');
var newinput = document.createElement('input');
var newbutton = document.createElement('button');

currentindex++;
newinput.type = "text";
newinput.name = 'input'+currentindex;
newinput.id = 'input'+currentindex;
newbutton.innerHTML="clickme";
newinput.onkeyup = addInput;
container.appendChild(newinput);
container.appendChild(newbutton);
```

### And here is the [Working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFqP6/1/)